# Getting a "InnerException: ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected" error in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, nhibernate

I have this oracle query:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K IS NULL
  THEN RAD_LAGER
  ELSE (
    SELECT PO.RAD_LAGER
    FROM PROSJEKT PO
    WHERE PO.PROSJEKT_K = P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K
  ) END AS RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL
  FROM PROSJEKT P
  WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K;
```

The query gives me an "InnerException: ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected" error, and I cant see where the error is. Anyone who immediately spots something that seems odd?

I tried encapsulating RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL is quotation marks and changing name to not contain "_".

The syntax does work in SQL developer, and the error appears when called in the code. I am interested in comparing P.PROSJEKT_S value to PROSJEKT_S value at line 15, where PROSJEKT_S is a foreign key to PROSJEKT table (P.PROSJEKT), hence the where clause at the end. "ProsjektLagetAv" uses a different table, which is why .Formula() is called, and "PROSJEKT_K" is mapped to the table present. I am using C# - mapping and constructing as follows:

```
Map(x => x.ProsjektLagetAv).Formula(@"(SELECT CASE WHEN P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K IS NULL THEN RAD_LAGER ELSE (SELECT PO.RAD_LAGER FROM PROSJEKT PO WHERE PO.PROSJEKT_K = P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K) END AS RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL FROM PROSJEKT P WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K)");
```

Constructor:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual string ProsjektLagetAv { get; set; }
PROSJEKT_K is always supplied, and is never null.

Map(x => x.ProsjektK, "PROSJEKT_K");
[DataMember]
public virtual string ProsjektK { get; set; }
```

SOLVED

NHibernate does something strange when mapping, and couldn't find the last FROM keyword. Solved by removing "AS RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL"

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K IS NULL
  THEN RAD_LAGER
  ELSE (
    SELECT PO.RAD_LAGER
    FROM PROSJEKT PO
    WHERE PO.PROSJEKT_K = P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K
  ) END
  FROM PROSJEKT P
  WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K;
```

Comment: That [appears to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/WUZagAmz). Is that exactly what you execute - does you real code have an unusual whitespace character perhaps, or is constructed and is actually missing whitespace? Also `P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K` will always be true (unless it's null); if this is part of a stored procedure then don't use argument names that are the same as column names. Perhaps showing how you call this and what else is going on will show the error is actually somewhere else - how you call a function, for example.

Comment: Enable NHibernate sql-logging and post the generated query. Columns without prefix get the prefix of the outer query when executed and there might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Oracle is concerned, syntax is OK:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     prosjekt (prosjekt_k, orginal_prosjekt_k, rad_lager)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, 1, 100 FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT CASE
  6            WHEN P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K IS NULL
  7            THEN
  8               RAD_LAGER
  9            ELSE
 10               (SELECT PO.RAD_LAGER
 11                  FROM PROSJEKT PO
 12                 WHERE PO.PROSJEKT_K = P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K)
 13         END AS RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL
 14    FROM PROSJEKT P
 15   WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K;

RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL
------------------
               100

SQL>
```

However, note that `where` clause in line #15 is probably wrong. That's

```
WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K;
                     ----------
                     what is this?
```

Oracle treats it as if it were `where 1 = 1` or no condition at all. If `prosjekt_k` is a parameter you pass to a procedure (or something similar), you should not use the same name as column name. Use e.g. `par_prosjekt_k`.

Comment: To be precise `where PROSJEKT_K is not null`, because `something = something` is true only for not null values

Answer (score 0):

For some reason NHibernate does something strange when mapping, and can't find the last FROM keyword in a single case clause. Solved by removing "AS RAD_LAGER_ORIGINAL"

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K IS NULL
  THEN RAD_LAGER
  ELSE (
    SELECT PO.RAD_LAGER
    FROM PROSJEKT PO
    WHERE PO.PROSJEKT_K = P.ORGINAL_PROSJEKT_K
  ) END
  FROM PROSJEKT P
  WHERE P.PROSJEKT_K = PROSJEKT_K;
```